# Pandas Apply and Loc - efficiency and indexing

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-loc

I want to find the first value after each row that meets a certain criteria. So for example I want to find the first rate/value (not necessarily the first *row* after) after the current row that increased 5%.  The added column would be the last 'first5percentIncrease' and would be the index (and/or value) of the first row (after current row) that had a 5% increase. Notice how each could not be lower than the current row's index.

```
          amount    date    rate    total   type first5percentIncreaseValue first5percentIncreaseIndex
9248    0.05745868  2018-01-22 06:11:36 10  0.00099984  buy 10.5 9341
9249    1.14869147  2018-01-22 06:08:38 20  0.01998989  buy 21 9421
9250    0.16498080  2018-01-22 06:02:59 15  0.00286241  sell 15.75 9266
9251    0.02881844  2018-01-22 06:01:54 2   0.00049999  sell 2.1 10911
```

I tried using loc to apply() this to each row. The output takes at least 10 seconds for only about 9k rows. This does the job (I get a list of all values 5% higher than the given row) but is there a more efficient way to do this?  Also I'd like to get only the first value but when I take do this I think it's starting from the first row. Is there a way to start .locs search from the current row so then I could just take the first value?

```
coin_trade_history_df['rate'].apply(
    lambda y: coin_trade_history_df['rate'].loc[coin_trade_history_df['rate'].apply(
        lambda x: y  >= x + (x*.005))])

0    [0.01387146, 0.01387146, 0.01387148, 0.0138714...
1    [0.01387146, 0.01387146, 0.01387148, 0.0138714...
2    [0.01387146, 0.01387146, 0.01387148, 0.0138714...
3    [0.01387146, 0.01387146, 0.01387148, 0.0138714...
4    [0.01387146, 0.01387146, 0.01387148, 0.0138714...
Name: rate, dtype: object
```

Further clarification [Peter Leimbigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008776/peter-leimbigler) said it better than me:

Oh, I think I get it now! "For each row, scan downward and get the first row you encounter that shows an increase of at least 5%," right? I'll edit my answer :) – Peter Leimbigler

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is to precompute a column of percent changes from the previous row, and then to select rows based on boolean indexing of the new column.

Comment: Good idea - but not ideal; That only accounts for the previous row/minute. I would then need to precompute a column for each 'shift'/row which could work since usually a measly .5% increase usually seems to happen within 90 minutes = 90 additional columns - not out of the question though thanks!

Comment: It would greatly help if you could post a small sample dataframe and show desired results, or else it's really hard for anyone to test their answer.  I added numpy/numba tags because those approaches will likely be much faster for a problem of this sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach to the specific example of labeling each row with the index of the next available row that shows an increase of at least 5%.

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'rate': [100, 105, 99, 110, 130, 120, 98]})

# Series.shift(n) moves elements n places forward = down. We use
# it here in the denominator in order to compare each change with 
# the initial value, rather than the final value.

mask = df.rate.diff()/df.rate.shift() >= 0.05

df.loc[mask, 'next_big_change_idx'] = df[mask].index
df.next_big_change_idx = df.next_big_change_idx.bfill().shift(-1)

# output
df
   rate  next_big_change_idx
0   100                  1.0
1   105                  3.0
2    99                  3.0
3   110                  4.0
4   130                  NaN
5   120                  NaN
6    98                  NaN
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am looking for but very pythonic :) I clarified the wording because I understand the confusion "So for example I want to find the first rate/value (not necessarily the first row after) after the current row that increased 5%. "

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now! "For each row, scan downward and get the first row you encounter that shows an increase of at least 5%," right? I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: Yup - I actually added your explanation to the question itself

Comment: @LiamHanninen, I've edited my answer - hope this is closer to what you're looking for. There may well be a faster and/or one-line solution, but at least this should be faster than nested `apply`!

Comment: Wow - much better than mine. Unfortunately the 'next_big_change' surfaces on the it's own row as well. For example row4/index3 has a rate of 110 but references index3 (itself) as the next_big_change. I would want 99 and 105 to show this actually.

Comment: @LiamHanninen, I missed that detail. How about adding `df.next_big_change_idx = df.next_big_change_idx.shift(-1)`? (I'll edit this into the answer)

Comment: Perfect - thanks and much more efficient than my original way!

Comment: Great to hear and happy coding!

Comment: This actually does not solve my issue. Would you be able to use the stackoverflow chat to discuss this? If not no biggie. But if I change my df df = pd.DataFrame({'rate': [100, 104.9,105, 99, 110, 130, 120, 98]}) to then it doesn't show that 3 is the big_change for 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164112/discussion-between-peter-leimbigler-and-liam-hanninen).

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer was much faster but it only looked at the immediate next row. I wanted it to perform this on every row. Below is what I ended up with - not very fast but it goes through each row and returns the first value (or last value in my case since my time series was descending) that satisfied my criteria (increasing 5%).

```
def test_rows(x):
    return trade_history_df['rate'].loc[
        trade_history_df['rate'] >= x['rate'] + (x['rate'] * .05)].loc[
        trade_history_df['date'] > x['date']].last_valid_index()

test1 = trade_history_df[['rate','date']].apply(test_rows,axis = 1)
```